# Mootool bind in form cannot clear

Tags: mootools

I am new to Mootools and here are the problem:
URL: http://dev.office-directory.partyapm.com/office-search
when I submit a search at the right side of the page choosing some "Amenities :" and clicking the "List properties" button. The "Amenities" cannot be clear by the "Clear" button. And those amenities will be there even if page refresh.

I debug the java scripts in chrome and seem those data reapply after some mootools function. 
Can someone please help, thanks.

Comment: I think your problem is that the `checked` state of the inputs is not removed by a reset button if the page was loaded with them checked. You will need some JS/MooTools to do that for you. Try adding `$$('form input[type="reset"]').addEvent('click', function(e){  e.preventDefault(); $$('.amenities input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(i){ i.removeProperty('checked');}); });` inside a `domready` function. Let us know if that is what you needed so we can provide a more complete answer.

Comment: Thanks Sergio, it work to clear the checked state. But one more issue is when I click the clear and do a page refresh/change to other page, the amenities appear again. Not sure where did it stored. Anyway I can clear it fully? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Maybe you should do a form submit together with the clear, so it comes from server side with the wished checked/unchecked state.

Comment: @dragonself add `autocomplete="off"` to elements you don't want to be re-populated after a reload or apply it to the form itself.